# Is there a way to assign/connect more hidden neurons to groups of input features based on their importance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a single hidden layer NN, with 100 input features and 1000 hidden neurons. After seeing the NN results, and the weights in which the model assigns to the input-hidden layer connections from the initial model run [therefore plotting the absolute weight and ranking the input features], I was wondering if there is a way to assign/ connect more neurons to groups of input features (G1: 70% of the hidden neurons, G220% and G3 to be connected to 10% of the hidden neurons). Lets say I have identified 3 groups of input data (G1: highly important, G2: intermediate important and finally G3:least important).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much of a point. If you have connections going from your inputs to the first layer of neurons, then back propagation will determine the proper weight values for those connections; if the connections were useless, then the weights would be near zero; these weights being zero for some input connections is similar to what you want. By removing/adding connections in the way that you are envisioning, you'd effectively be removing information from the network, since in the original structure the weights are most likely not near zero after back propagation (meaning they hold some relevance to predicting the outputs).

That being said, if you are really convinced you know better weights than the back propagation results, then train the model and then scale the weights from the trained model afterwards to how you want it to be, which would result in what you are saying.

You can get and set the weights of your model's first layer by doing:

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
model.layers[0].set_weights(my_weights)
```

If you really want to do it as you are describing, here is the code below which you can modify for that and get an idea of how it works:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

"""
Initialize the inputs and output
"""
x_1 = np.arange(10).reshape(1, 2, 5)
x_2 = np.arange(20, 36).reshape(1, 2, 8)
x_3 = np.arange(40, 60).reshape(1, 2, 10)
y = np.array([5])

"""
Create the input layers to feed the input values into
"""
first_input = Input(shape=(2, 5,), name="FirstInput")
second_input = Input(shape=(2, 8,), name="SecondInput")
third_input = Input(shape=(2, 10,), name="ThirdInput")

"""
Create the initial dense layers to connect the inputs to, with varying neurons for each input
"""
first_dense = Dense(3, use_bias=False, name="FirstDense")(first_input)
second_dense = Dense(2, use_bias=False, name="SecondDense")(second_input)
third_dense = Dense(1, use_bias=False, name="ThirdDense")(third_input)

"""
Create the models for each input segment
"""
first_model = Model(inputs=first_input, outputs=first_dense, name="FirstModel")
second_model = Model(inputs=second_input, outputs=second_dense, name="SecondModel")
third_model = Model(inputs=third_input, outputs=third_dense, name="ThirdModel")

"""
Concatenate the outputs of each input model and feed them into a singular model
"""
concat_layers = concatenate([first_model.output, second_model.output, third_model.output])
output = Dense(1, name="OutputLayer")(concat_layers)
singular_model = Model(inputs=(first_model.input, second_model.input, third_model.input), outputs=output,
                       name="CombinedModel")
singular_model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
singular_model.fit(x=(x_1, x_2, x_3), y=y, epochs=2)
```

The idea is that you create models for each input segment that work in parallel, concatenate their outputs, and feed that into a singular model; this could be similar to having a single model with the varying amounts of node connections for each input.

So instead of your envisioned version:

Z(x) = w1 * x1 + w2 * x1 + w3 * x1 + w4 * x2 + w5 * x2 + w6 * x3 + w0

You would instead feed the inputs into their own separate models, each of which consists of its own dense layer (without bias), and get outputs for each node in the layers, e.g. one neuron output from each layer would look like:

Z1(x) = w1 * x1 + w2 * x1 + w3 * x1

Z2(x) = w4 * x2 + w5 * x2

Z3(x) = w6 * x3

These separate output segments could then be combined by running them through a dense layer, and this time you could include the bias:

Z(x) = w7 * Z1(x) + w8 * Z2(x) + w9 * Z3(x) + w0

Z(x) = w7 * (w1 * x1 + w2 * x1 + w3 * x1) + w8 * (w4 * x2 + w5 * x2) + w9 * (w6 * x3) + w0

As I'm sure you can see, there is an extra weight for each output, since the concatenated layer is being fed into a new layer as an input. If you think this will be a problem, you can get around it by doing:

```
from keras.initializers.initializers_v2 import Ones
ones_initializer = Ones()
output = Dense(1, name="OutputLayer", kernel_initializer=ones_initializer, trainable=False)(concat_layers)
```

This code initializes the weights to ones, and then prevents them from being trained/modified in the future. This would essentially ignore the secondary weights (w7, w8, w9) since it would be the identity property.

That would turn it into:

Z(x) = 1 * (w1 * x1 + w2 * x1 + w3 * x1) + 1 * (w4 * x2 + w5 * x2) + 1 * (w6 * x3) + w0

Z(x) = w1 * x1 + w2 * x1 + w3 * x1 + w4 * x2 + w5 * x2 + w6 * x3 + w0

Which is what you originally wanted.

You may want to set the dense layers in the parallel models to include bias and not use bias on this layer however, since it wouldn't be trainable. This should be just fine, since back propagation would decide ideal values for them. Likewise, not setting the weights to ones should also work fine, since back propagation would set them to one if that truly was their best value. If you really want to use a bias, but do not want a bias for each parallel model, you could set just one parallel model to include a bias, which would have the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess I was thinking to do similar thing as a partially connected network meaning certain input features (Group 1) have 70% of the Hidden Neurons connected to them, not necessarily the weights, but the number of single-hidden-layer neurons connected to each input group (G1, G2, G3).

Comment: You can do it if you really want to, but I don't think there won't be any point unless you add some differences between the models. I added the code to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Can you elaborate what are first_input, second_input, first_dense, second_dense, first_model and the  second_model?

Comment: I edited the original post to include code that you can run and an explanation of the model/mathematical thinking behind it.

Comment: In running the model.fit_generator , I get this error: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'tuple'> containing values of types {"<class 'partition_class_nrap.data_generator_nrap'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>    hist = singular_model.fit_generator(generator=(training_generator_1, training_generator_2, training_generator_3),validation_data = (calibration_generator_1, calibration_generator_2, calibration_generator_3), epochs = n_epoch,

Comment: Followed up on my last comment, here is my data generator and inputs:         
df_array_1 = df_array[:,class_1_input].reshape(1, 23000000, 75)

df_array_2 = df_array[:,class_2_input].reshape(1, 23000000, 35)

df_array_3 = df_array[:,class_3_input].reshape(1, 23000000, 40)

Comment: training_generator_1 = data_generator(df_array_1, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx, input_cols_idx,train_idx,
                                        partition_set = 'Training',gen_indices = True, shuffle=False)
    
training_generator_2 = data_generator(df_array_2, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx, input_cols_idx,train_idx,
                                        partition_set = 'Training',gen_indices = True, shuffle=False)

Comment: training_generator_3 = data_generator(df_array_3, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx, input_cols_idx,train_idx,
                                        partition_set = 'Training',gen_indices = True, shuffle=False)

Comment: Same for calibration: calibration_generator_1 = data_generator(df_array_1, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx,input_cols_idx,calibration_idx,
                                           partition_set = 'Calibration',gen_indices = False)
    
calibration_generator_2 = data_generator(df_array_2, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx,input_cols_idx,calibration_idx,
                                           partition_set = 'Calibration',gen_indices = False)

Comment: calibration_generator_3 = data_generator(df_array_3, batch_size_gen, target_col_idx,input_cols_idx,calibration_idx,
                                           partition_set = 'Calibration',gen_indices = False)